# Snakemake - Jupyter lab notebook does not find kernel

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, snakemake, jupyter-kernel

When writing a program in a jupyter lab notebook using R or python I install specific conda environments as kernels to access that environment-specific packages from a single jupyter lab installation in the base conda environment

After finishing developing the notebook I want to plug it into my snakemake file to ensure later reproducibility and of course, I do that with the respective conda environment .yaml file so that all the needed packages/libraries are provided.

Now comes the problem: the rule which references the notebook, is not reproducible on another machine/environment, as it tries to access/run a kernel which is specific to my development environment

Does anyone have a workaround or solution to this particular problem?

EDIT:
**More detailed steps leading to my problem**

1. Setup a conda environment (matplotlib_env) for a specific tool or task (here: matplotlib)

```sh
conda create -n matplotlib_env python=3.8 ipykernel matplotlib nbconvert
```

2. I created a ipython kernel so my jupyter-lab instance **from the base environment** can access the conda environment and the respective packages (matplotlib)

```sh
python -m ipykernel install --user --name matplotlib_env --display-name "Python_maplotlib"
```

3. I created a short notebook ([1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zt9tL.png)) that uses the kernel configured in step 2 (Pyhton_matplotlib [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGEZ5.png))

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3],[1,4,9])
plt.savefig('exp.png')
```

4. Having finished the task I want to plug it into my snakemake workflow for management and reproducibility reasons. For that, I define a rule, with the respective notebook and conda environment .yaml file (automatically generated via: `conda env export > matplotlib_env.yaml`).

```py
rule make_plot:
    output:
        "exp.png"
    conda:
        "matplotlib_env.yaml"
    notebook:
        "make_plot.ipynb"
```

5. Executing the rule works fine as long as the original conda environment (with the configured kernel) still exists. As soon as I remove the original conda environment (optionally also the kernel from the kernelspec list) I get an error message, as the kernel can not be found anymore and the snakemake generated conda environment does not possess the kernel, the notebook is looking for.

```sh
snakemake -p --cores 1 --use-conda make_plot
```

ERROR message after removing the original environment

```
[NbConvertApp] ERROR | Failed to run command:
...
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/miniconda3/envs/matplotlib_env/bin/python'
```

ERROR message after removing kernel from kernel list

```
...
raise NoSuchKernel(kernel_name)
jupyter_client.kernelspec.NoSuchKernel: No such kernel named matplotlib_env
```

Comment: Are you running with `--use-conda`?  Can you post the notebook rule and conda yaml?  I've not used a specific conda environment for notebook rules, but it should work.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response and interest!
Yes, I am using --use-conda.
I have edited the original post and added a minimal example of the problem I am facing.

Comment: Hi , did you ever find a solution to this? Running into this now.

Comment: Hi, nothing better than my workaround below. Personally, I recommend using notebooks either for interactive development and then generate a script for your workflow or when the processed notebook has a purpose (e.g., communication or tutorial).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround:
Before saving your notebook the last time switch kernel to the default python or R kernel from your base environment. These always have the same default name post-installation (eg "Python 3"). Thereby, when executed via snakemake the notebook looks for the default Python/R kernel and finds the new installation provided via the snakemake --use-conda option.

This is not the most elegant version, but if you need/want to plug notebooks into your workflow, it is good enough.

The most rigorous would be to turn the notebook, once done, into a script with clearly defined input and outputs. This script is then plugged into the snakefile, via a corresponding rule, instead of the notebook.